# jQuery car make/model and specs from scratch.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i'm trying to create a car make/model for a specific brand and set them to a `<div>` and create a tile in bootstrap. but i don't know where to start. i'm not good with jQuery or javascript but i have basic knowledge with them. hope you could help me. thanks

Comment: A good start point is to choose one of bootstrap templates freely available on their website and modify it for your needs.

Comment: yea i can possibly do that. it would be harder to maintain in a long run.

Comment: Choose a starter simple Bootstrap template and start coding and updating

Comment: @jmv What do you mean?

Comment: @MirazChowdhury i mean i can do that like use cards. for template then update it manually each make/model line i need. but it's better to use jquery right? . where i can just add an array and it will automatically update. each html tag.